# Mutate a Vec element with a capturing pattern match

Tags: design-patterns, rust, match, capture, mutable

I can change the last element of a vec:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Type {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![Type::A, Type::B, Type::B];
    
    match v.last_mut(){
        None => v.push(Type::A),
        Some(last) => *last = Type::C,
    }
    
    println!("{:?}", v)
}
```

==> prints `[A, B, C]`.

But if my enum constants have data, I can't seem to capture them anymore... For example this compiles:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Type {
    A(i32),
    B(i32),
    C(i32),
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![Type::A(0), Type::B(1), Type::B(2)];
    
    match v.last_mut(){
        None => v.push(Type::A(0)),
        Some(last @ Type::B(_)) => *last = Type::C(42),
        Some(Type::A(_)) | Some(Type::C(_)) => {}
    }
    
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

==> prints `[A(0), B(1), C(42)]`

This worked just because I put `_` inside `Type::B(_)` pattern.
But if I try to capture it to use in `Type::C()` with this:

```rust
        Some(last @ Type::B(p)) => *last = Type::C(*p),
```

I get these three errors:

```
error: borrow of moved value
  --> src/main.rs:13:14
   |
13 |         Some(last @ Type::B(p)) => *last = Type::C(*p),
   |              ----^^^^^^^^^^^-^
   |              |              |
   |              |              value borrowed here after move
   |              value moved into `last` here
   |              move occurs because `last` has type `&mut Type` which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0658]: pattern bindings after an `@` are unstable
  --> src/main.rs:13:29
   |
13 |         Some(last @ Type::B(p)) => *last = Type::C(*p),
   |                             ^
   |
   = note: see issue #65490 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65490> for more information

error[E0382]: borrow of moved value
  --> src/main.rs:13:29
   |
13 |         Some(last @ Type::B(p)) => *last = Type::C(*p),
   |              ---------------^-
   |              |              |
   |              |              value borrowed here after move
   |              value moved here
   |
   = note: move occurs because value has type `&mut Type`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
help: borrow this field in the pattern to avoid moving the value
   |
13 |         Some(ref last @ Type::B(p)) => *last = Type::C(*p),
   |              ^^^

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

How could I make this work, i.e. capture the current value of B (an `&mut i32`), and pass it to C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capturing `last` mutably and the value inside it immutably would mean that you hold both a `mut` reference and a shared reference to the same data at the same time. Rust's ownership model prohibits such aliasing, so the borrow checker rejects it.

> How could I make this work, i.e. capture the current value of B (a `&mut i32`), and pass it to C?

You can capture the last value and examine it in a separate inner match. This avoids the initial request for aliased references which is a problem for Rust. Instead, it creates the inner `p` reference from the outer `last` reference, which is allowed as long as the outer reference is not used during the lifetime of the inner reference. In other words, this compiles:

```
match v.last_mut() {
    None => v.push(Type::A(0)),
    Some(last) => {
        match last {
            Type::B(p) => *last = Type::C(*p),
            Type::A(_) | Type::C(_) => (),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=58748b8c0a3d1d015ff8ce6933297c90)

Comment: That's very nice, thanks! Only I'm not sure why it does work... Why splitting in two matches Rust's ownership model doesn't detect aliasing anymore? Aren't `last` captured mutably and the value inside it immutably like it was before?

Comment: @rsalmei That's a good question. My mental model is that in the nested-match version the inner match creates a shared reference based on the outer `mut` reference in `last`. This is allowed as long as you don't use the outer reference while the inner one is live (and it must be allowed, otherwise you wouldn't be able to do anything useful with a `&mut` reference, such as accessing the data inside it!) - and indeed in my case we drop it. In your original code the match pattern requests a mut and non-mut reference to the same data, which is aliasing.

Comment: @rsalmei I believe the code in your question is equivalent to trying to do [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=24db7e388ee8b1c317b020a0dd76c13d) (which doesn't compile), while the code in my answer is equivalent to [this reformulation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f471c4dec261984b54e086b00fcc63f3) (which compiles). In this simpler case we could also change `let r2: &Foo = &foo` to `let r2: &Foo = r1`, but you can't tell `match` to do that, you have to create a new inner match based on `r1`.

Comment: Indeed, the post-NLL rustc is smart enough to allow "aliasing" when the inner reference is not used after the outer one: for example [this compiles as well](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=17e63f1d54dc46577f7809fc2f6f247e). But if you try to even touch `*p` after the assignment to `*last`, it will [no longer compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7bfaac5172bc39508c4bbdcb4fba88da).

Comment: Wow, you nailed it!! Thank you very much! The "downgrade" of the reference to a shared one, and the NLL examples does explain it!

Comment: @rsalmei Thanks for asking the followup question, things are now clearer to me as well. I've amended the answer to use the simpler formulation.